# Go YAML parsing: mandatory fields

Tags: go

Summary:
I need to parse data in YAML format into golang struct. It there a way (library, attributes) to make some of the fields mandatory, i.e. to make Unmarshal function return the error in case if some field doesn't exist?

Example what is wanted:
Unmarshal function in this code should raise an error because input data doesn't contain 'b' field.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type TestStruct struct {
    FieldA string `yaml:"a"`
    FieldB string `yaml:"b"`
}

func main() {
    input := []byte(`{a: 1}`)
    var output TestStruct

    _ = yaml.Unmarshal(input, &output)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [library](https://godoc.org/github.com/fatih/structs)'s `HasZero` method to check wether there are any missing values in a struct. This will return true or false depending wether the struct is completely filled or not. Please see the playground [example](https://play.golang.org/p/VsQDGZZmaZI) to get an idea.

But if you specifically need to tell what field is missing, you need to check wether the value is nil like in the example below.

```
package main
import (
   "fmt"
   "errors"
  "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type TestStruct struct {
  FieldA  string `yaml:"a"`
  FieldB  string `yaml:"b"`
}

func main() {
  input := []byte(`{a: 1}`)

  var output TestStruct 
  if err := output.ParseFromFile(input); err != nil {
     fmt.Println(err)
  }
  fmt.Println(output)     
}

func (output *TestStruct) ParseFromFile(data []byte) error {

  if err := yaml.Unmarshal(data, output); err != nil {
    return err
  }

  if output.FieldA == "" {
    return errors.New("Blank Field A")
  }
  if output.FieldB == "" {
    return errors.New("Blank Field B")
  }

  return nil
}
```

Playground [example](https://play.golang.org/p/caHzembswOu) if you need to specifically return an error

Comment: Awesome, HasZero method is almost exact what I need. @sanoJ, thank you!

Comment: A YAML field may be set with an empty string `""` - so the above check would give a false positive in this case. One may or may not care about this edge case. If one does, use a `*string` & unmarshal will leave this `nil` for any missing fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a required flag to your struct annotations:

```
type TestStruct struct {
    FieldA string `yaml:"a" validate:"required"`
    FieldB string `yaml:"b" validate:"required"`
}
```